# Connection to oracle database

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, ide, connection

Hi I am new enough to java and I am trying to create a connection from it to my sql database. using Netbeans I managed to set up a connection easily enough. The issue is when I try to connect using my code I get driver not found. Is there something wrong with what I have?

```
 //function to execute the insert update delete query
  public void theQuery(String query){
      Connection con = null;
      Statement st = null;
      try{
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@redwood.ict.ad.dit.ie:1521:pdb12c.ict.ad.dit.ie", "eocribin","");
          st = con.createStatement();
          st.executeUpdate(query);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Query Executed");
      }catch(Exception ex){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
      }
  }
```

Comment: Add Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

Comment: That worked I had to add the driver thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to add oracle thin driver into your projects library and then restart the IDE to take notice of changes. Make sure that oracle's server is running when you run this code. Also check the username and password.

Java Persistence in netbeans is a much better option then using Oracle thin driver in your code. Because it saves much of your time typing and harcoding. JPA(Java Persistence API) allows you to easily add the oracle's thin driver from its menu and reduces much of your time. It is used in enterprise applications . You should try this and watch its tutorials on the following site.

These are called JPA tutorials. 
http://www.programming-simplified.com